# Multi-Line (separate lines) output in AIML?

Tags: chat, chatbot, aiml

I want the user to ask a question, and then the chat bot responds in different lines but in order.

Comment: I don't see a question here. Explain what your problem is and what you've already tried.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the interpreter, you may be able to use the line break tags that HTML uses.

```
 <br/>
```

They can be used like this:

```
<category>
    <pattern>WHO INVENTED LINUX</pattern>
    <template>
        Linus Torvalds, along with many open source developers, and the Free Software Foundation, GNU invented Linux.<br/>
        Linus Torvalds invented Linux in 1991.
        <think>
            <set name="topic">computers</set>
        </think>
    </template>
</category>
```

Answer (score 0):

For newer AIML versions, considering the age and still relevance of this question, 
 is still valid, and the use of  could be combined with it in the templates. 
However, be careful that these responses (utterances) will include the break-tags and other things, making context with  painful to debug.